# How to use angular.bootstrap twice?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where there are few tabs and I use angular+bootstrap. 
I use angular.bootstrap initially. 
Then I have another controller for showing different set of data in one of the tabs. when I try to use angular.bootstrap again, I get the error it cannot be bootstrapped twice. To make it simple, consider the following code.

```
    <div id="mainpage" ng-controller="mainPageController">
    <ul>

    <li id="test1"> <a href="gototest1"> GoToTest1  </li>
    <li id="test2"> <a href="gototest2"> GoToTest2 </li>

    </ul>
    </div>


<div id="gototest1"> 
this is some sample. I have another html page here which will be loaded as a tab
</div
```

The page for gototest1 looks like this

```
    <div ng-controller="gototestcontroller>
    Here comes the another widget from another controller and 
I try to use angular.boostrap here again. And I get the error because it is already bootstrapped in mainPage

    </div>
```

What is the best way to use angular.bootstrap here?

Comment: what do you mean with angular.bootstrap?, where is the error I cant see it

Answer (score 0):

Angular bootstrap is used to manually initialize an Angular the document or an element.
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Angular cannot be initialized more than once on an element. Is there a reason you don't use automatic initialization, using `ng-app`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could benefit from using the module `ngRoute` and applying the attirbute `ng-view` instead of trying to bootstrap twice.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute